# as.Date function doesn't convert date

Tags: r

I have a small problem with the `as.Date` function. I loaded a prn data as csv file, and my teacher said it was okay, then when I try to set my dates in the standard way (y,m,d) it gives me as a year a crazy number. PZU file is the stock prices for polish company. Also, I am not really sure how to set time also. I would really appreciate the help. Just for general info I am using R software with R studio interface.

```
pzu<-read.csv("PZU.prn",header=F)[,1:7]
names(pzu)<-c("name","date","time","open","high","low","close")
head(pzu)
#  name     date time open high low close
#1  PZU 20100512  845  349  349 349   349
#2  PZU 20100512  845  349  349 349   349
#3  PZU 20100512  845  349  349 349   349
#4  PZU 20100512  845  349  349 349   349
#5  PZU 20100512  845  349  349 349   349
#6  PZU 20100512  845  349  349 349   349

class(pzu$date) # output is an "integer"

str(pzu)
#data.frame':   960638 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ name : Factor w/ 1 level "PZU": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ date : int  20100512 20100512 20100512 20100512 20100512 20100512 20100512 20100512 20100512 20100512 ...
# $ time : int  845 845 845 845 845 845 845 845 845 845 ...
# $ open : num  349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 ...
# $ high : num  349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 ...
# $ low  : num  349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 ...
# $ close: num  349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 349 ...

pzu$date<-as.Date(pzu$date)
head(pzu)
#name       date time open high low close
#1  PZU 7003-05-03  845  349  349 349   349
#2  PZU 7003-05-03  845  349  349 349   349
#3  PZU 7003-05-03  845  349  349 349   349
#4  PZU 7003-05-03  845  349  349 349   349
#5  PZU 7003-05-03  845  349  349 349   349
#6  PZU 7003-05-03  845  349  349 349   349
```

Answer (score 8):

Your dates are not in a format `as.Date()` recognizes. First, convert them to character using `as.character()`, then specify the correct format via the `format` parameter to `as.Date()`:

```
as.Date(as.character(20100512),format="%Y%m%d")
```

Alternatively, you could add in the time variable by converting to `POSIXct`. Convert the date as above. Take the hundreds in the time variable, multiply by 3600 (3600 seconds to an hour) and add. Take the remainder, multiply by 60 (60 seconds to a minute) and add again:

```
date.num <- 20100512
time.num <- 845
as.POSIXct(as.character(date.num),format="%Y%m%d") +
(time.num%/%100)*3600 +
(time.num%%100)*60

"2010-05-12 08:45:00 CEST"
```

Look at `?POSIXct` for all the fun things R can do with times and dates.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you very much. I appreciate it. Also, could you please tell me how I could format the time also, the class of time is "integer". I want it to look like stand time format, such as: 8:45 Thank you very much again.

Comment: @user3157869: I edited the answer to also convert times, hope it helps.